# How to add custom directive to Angular Material Dialog component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

I've created a custom directive that adds an additional `@Output()` event to Ionic's `ion-range` element. It works well on normal pages, but when I try and use it within Angular Material's `Dialog` component, the custom event isn't firing for some reason. My custom directives are added to a Directives module, and I typically import this Directives module where I need to use it. Here's how my project is set up:

**range-events.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
    selector: 'ion-range'
})
export class RangeEventsDirective {

    @Output() public ionStart: EventEmitter<RangeValue> = new EventEmitter();

    public constructor(protected elemRef: ElementRef<IonRange>) {}

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
    public onStart(ev: Event): void {
        this.ionStart.emit(this.elemRef.nativeElement.value);
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

}
```

This directive is declared and exported here:

**directives.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    RangeEventsDirective,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    RangeEventsDirective,
    ...
  ]
})
export class DirectivesModule { }
```

I've defined a custom pop up component, that shows on hover, with an edit button. When this edit button is clicked, it creates my Dialog component.

Here's my popup component:

**edit-kit-popup.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-kit-popup',
  templateUrl: './edit-kit-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-kit-popup.component.scss'],
})
export class EditKitPopupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  edit() {
    const modalRef = this.dialog.open(EditKitSectionModalComponent, {
      width: '320px',
      height: '476px',
      position: {
        top: '20px',
        right: '20px'
      },
      data: {
        ...
      }
    });
  }

}
```

As you can see I use a custom component to display the dialog, that is defined in: `edit-kit-section-modal.component.ts`.

This dialog has an `ion-range` element with the `@Output()` event, I've added in `edit-kit-section-modal.component.html:

```
<ion-range #sectionHeightRange (ionStart)="customRangeStart($event)"></ion-range>
```

Both of these components are defined and exported in the following modules file. I then import my `DirectivesModule` here so that I can use the directives in the components:

**press-kit-components.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    MaterialModule,
    PipesModule,
    IonicModule,
    ...
    DirectivesModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
    EditKitItemPopupComponent,
    EditKitSectionModalComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    EditKitItemPopupComponent,
    EditKitSectionModalComponent,
  ]
})
export class PressKitComponentsModule { }
```

Since I am using a custom component, I make sure to add the `EditKitSectionModalComponent` as an `entryComponent` in my page where the popup is used.

Is the reason why it is not registering, because the Dialog isn't present on the page at page load? So when I trigger the Dialog, the directive isn't applied?

**How should I be using custom directives with an Angular Material Dialog component?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, when I changed my selector from:

```
@Directive({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
    selector: 'ion-range'
})
```

to:

```
@Directive({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
    selector: '[ion-range-events]'
})
```

and added the directive like this:

```
<ion-range ion-range-events #sectionHeightRange (ionStart)="customRangeStart($event)"></ion-range>
```

It worked...anyone know why I can't call by the HTML selector like I did in my original question? Because calling by selector `ion-range` worked on non-dialog components. Thanks!